# access a child stackedwidget (PySide 6)

Tags: pyside6

I'm trying to access a stacked child with PySide6, but when I try to select the child, it just selects the parent. The call is like this`(self.ui.NFCE_C.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.pages.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.ui_pages.STACKED_NFCE).`

Is there any way to access the child qstackedwidget?

[image: Image1]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].